# How can I see the post rendering without MathJax formatting?

Tags: support, markdown, mathjax

While I'm studying Math, Physics or any other topics which uses a lot of formulas, I'm taking notes using [Anki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anki_(software)) which supports MathJax formating. Since I'd like my notes to be properly formated, I want to copy the MathJax-code. As it currently stands, I have to try and figure out how it is formated and then rewrite it.

I have searched for ways to render Stack Exchange without formating applied, but all for vain.

**My question**: is there some way to copy raw Math-Jax from a post?

Comment: Use the edit link.

Comment: @Rob Thanks, exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can either

1. click the "edit" link on the post (alternatively, the URL takes the form of `https://[site].stackexchange.com/posts/[postID]/edit`), or
2. right click on the rendered MathJax, choose "Show Math As" and then "TeX commands", or
3. view the "source" of a certain revision (easier for questions that have been edited at least once, since a "revisions" link will already be readily available). The link takes the form of `https://site.stackexchange.com/revisions/[somerandomcharacters]/view-source`. For example, [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/21209/221563)'s revision [6](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/21209/revisions) [source](https://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/51a7b085-a12d-4350-8613-06b950728298/view-source).